# C Searching Values in Array stored with random integers

Tags: c, arrays

my program generates random values, stores them into an array and allows the user to search for values generated until he/she no longer wants to. My code written works, but after around the 5th or 6th time searching for a value, my program outputs "Value not found" when the value searched for is clearly generated. My question is, what can be causing my search function to not output the value searched position after a few times of looping through it?
My code is here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void ranNum(int *ptr, int SIZE, int MIN, int MAX); // random number generator prototype
void search(int *ptr, int SIZE, int MAX, int MIN); // search for value in array prototype
void error(int num);

int main(){
    srand(time(NULL)); /* initialize random seed: */
    int x = 1;
    int *ptr = NULL;
    int SIZE, MIN, MAX, y, z;

    printf("\nEnter size of your array: ");
    scanf("%d", &SIZE);
    if (SIZE < 100){
        error(0);
    }
    printf("Enter min: ");
    scanf("%d", &MIN);
    printf("Enter max: ");
    scanf("%d", &MAX);
    if (MIN >= MAX){
        y = MIN;
        z = MAX;
        MAX = y;
        MIN = z;

    }
    ptr = malloc(SIZE * sizeof(int));

    ranNum(ptr, SIZE, MIN, MAX);
    search(ptr, SIZE, MAX, MIN);
    free(ptr);
    printf("Enter 0 to exit: ");
    scanf("%d", &x);


}

void ranNum(int *ptr, int SIZE, int MIN, int MAX){ // random number generator definition
    int i = 0;
    for (i; i < SIZE; i++){
        ptr[i] = rand() % (MAX - MIN + 1) + MIN; /*generates random value between min and max*/
        printf("%d \t", *(ptr + i));
        if (i % 10 == 9)
        printf("\n"); // for every 10 elements print a new line
    }
}

void search(int *ptr, int SIZE, int MIN, int MAX){ // search for value definition
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int value;
    do{
        printf("Enter a value to search for: ");
        scanf("%d", &value);

        while (x <= SIZE && value != *(ptr + x)){ // begins to search array for value
            x++; // if value has not been found the index increases by 1 
        }

        if (x < SIZE){ // if value is found and is in the size of array
            printf("Value found at location %d \n", x + 1); // adds index by 1 to determine location
        }
        else {
            printf("Value not found!\n");
        }
        printf("Enter 1 to search again. ");
        scanf("%d", &y);
    } while (y == 1);
}

void error(int num){
    static char* err[] = { "Array size must be atleast 100 elements!\n",
   };
    printf("%s", err[num]);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Comment: You need to reset X back to 0 (or wherever your numbers begin in the array) otherwise it will only look starting from where the last number had been found.

Comment: Try putting `x = 0;` as the first line in the do{}while() loop.

Comment: Ah yes that makes sense! Thank you for the help Goodies! I was stuck on this error for a while now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never set `x` back to 0 for your second run through the loop in `search`.

I would probably have `search` just search for one value, and put the looping outside the search method. i.e. `void search(int target, int *ptr, int SIZE, int MIN, int MAX)`